# how to add attribute to sales_flat_invoice table

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, custom-attributes

What is the proper way to add new custom attribute to `sales_flat_invoice` table?

I need to extend this table in order to mark that the payment was made, so subsequent updates do not trigger connection to external system.

Comment: custom attribute mean new field to sales_flat_invoice table?

Comment: yes new field to sales_flat_invoice table

Answer (score 0):

The steps for create an custom attribute:

In order to full fill to create a custom attribute in the table,you need to Create a module.

On this extension using  mysql installer,create new field.

**Step1:** create config.xml where define the installer.***location***: `app/code/local/[ModuleNameSpace]/[ModuleName]/etc`

**Code:**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config>
>   <modules>
>     <[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]>
>       <version>1.0.0</version>
>     </[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]>
>   </modules>
>   <global>
>   <models>
>     <modulename>
>       <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model</class>
>
>     </modulename>
>   </models>
>   <resources>
>     <addsalesattribute_setup>
>       <setup>
>         <module>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]</module>
>         <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
>       </setup>
>       <connection>
>         <use>core_setup</use>
>       </connection>
>     </addsalesattribute_setup>
>     <addsalesattribute_write>
>       <connection>
>         <use>core_write</use>
>       </connection>
>     </addsalesattribute_write>
>     <addsalesattribute_read>
>       <connection>
>         <use>core_read</use>
>       </connection>
>     </addsalesattribute_read>
>   </resources>
>   </global>
> </config>
> ```

**Step2:** installer file which will add new columns at table

***location:*** `app/code/local/[ModuleNameSpace]/[ModuleName]/sql/addsalesattribute_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

**Code:**

> ```
> <?php
> $installer = $this;
> $installer->startSetup();
>
> $installer->addAttribute("invoice", "custom_field_one", array("type"=>"text"));
> $installer->endSetup();
> ```

**Step3:** create module file ***[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName].xml*** at `app/etc/modules/`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config>
>   <modules>
>     <[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]>
>       <active>true</active>
>       <codePool>local</codePool>
>   <depends>Mage_Sales</depends>      
>  </[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]>
>   </modules>
> </config>
> ```

Comment: thanks what will be setter and getter for that field? setCustomFieldOne and getCustomFieldOne?

Comment: after running above I am trying to do: desc sales_flat_invoice; but there is no "custom_field_one" attribute there. I have checked and the code in the installer is being run.

Comment: having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: What does the handlers `<addsalesattribute_write>` and `<addsalesattribute_read>` do? I created a module without these handler. All working fine. What is the need of it?